# Box keeps resizing Interface Builder

Tags: xcode

Still a n00b (sorry) and I wondered if there is a solution this rather simple quandry which I cannot find an answer for (probably because it is so simple).

Basically I have a label which is inside a custom box.  When I change the box size and then hit run the box size changes back to another random annoying size.  It sounds simple enough but can I change it so that it sticks to the definitions I set.  I have a series of labels and it would be great if the layout were the same.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off 'Live Autoresizing' in the menu.